# Upgrade to AndroidStudio 3.4 and now can´t run my app

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I updated my Android Studio to Android Studio 3.4 and I'm trying to run one of my apps but it gives me an error.

com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: No outputs for the main artifact of variant: debug

Session 'app': Install failed.
Installation failed
Rerun

Answer (score 8):

Solved it by going to Run => Edit Configuration => app (or your project name)

In the `Before Launch` section, I added `Gradle-aware Make`.

---

The hint came from comparing my project with the example screenshot available at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig#opening

Comment: wow. worked like magic. Thanks mate

Answer (score 3):

Try running your app after reloading your gradle project

[Right click over your project under Gradle tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqa5R.png)

Answer (score 1):

You may be using an incompatible Gradle and Android Gradle plugin version.

Upgrade Gradle to version 4.1 at least

in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

use:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

and in root `build.gradle`

modify the  following lines (add Google maven repository and update plugin to 3.0.1):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
On the left there is a pane where all the files are displayed called "Build Variants"
I selected that and my main app module was set to debug-x86. I changed that to debug-x86-64 and it worked[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvE7t.png)

Comment: Try "Invalidate Cache and Restart" in Android studio file option and then Clean build and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, delete Signed Bundle files you were created.